# function does not call other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that calls another function on success. I have used alerts as you can see and it goes up to alert "2".

On F12 press there is a 500 server error, but also I can see that my webservice does work because I see that it pulls all the data correctly in XML.  Also my `data: param` or query string gets the correct values.

JavaScript:

```
function ContactView()
{
    alert("1")
    var txtSearchbox = $("#searchTextField").val();
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: param = "searchField="+txtSearchbox+"&office="+localStorage.getItem("office")+"&person="+localStorage.getItem("person")+"&user="+localStorage.getItem("user")+"&organization="+localStorage.getItem("organization"),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://msw-wsdl.company.net/mobile.asmx/ContactGet",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successContact,
        failure: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
    alert("2")   /*this is the last alert that pop's up, nothing further*/
}
/*wsdl call succeed*/
function successContact(data) {
    alert("3")
    $("#lstView_contacts").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: JSON.parse(data.d),
        template: $("#lstView_contact_Template").html(),
        endlessScroll: true,
        scrollThreshold: 8
    });
    window.location = "#contactsview";
}
```

Why is the success callback `successContact` not called - any ideas?

Comment: There is no `failure` option, so **when** it fails due to the same origin policy you're not getting a "parse error" message in the console, change it to `error` instead.

Comment: @adeneo: I get a better error responce - `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"There was an error processing the request.\",\"StackTrace\":\"\",\"ExceptionType\":\"\"}","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"} `

Comment: You will never get a success until the 500 error is corrected. Check the data that you're sending to the server to make sure that it is correctly formatted to be used properly on the server side rather than generating the error.

Comment: And where are you getting that error message from ?

Answer (score 2):

Function `successContact` will get called only if it's *success*, and error 500 mean it's not success. The `error` method will get called instead which is not define on your case.

Comment: If you're using `cross-domain` request or `JSONP`, then `error` method will not get called. Have you try `done`, `fail`, and `always` method of jQuery ajax?